# Append HTML to a Sencha Touch Container/Panel

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I would like to create sort of an in-app console, so that our app can have a separate tab where we can output (and easily read) debugging information while we test it.

I'm new to Sencha Touch, but in jQuery it would be trivial to do something like:

```
window.log = function(msg) {
    $("#Console").append('<div>' + msg + '</div>');
}
```

My Main.js view includes the following:

```
{
    title: 'Console',
    iconCls: 'info',
    scrollable: true,

    items: [
        {
            docked: 'top',
            xtype: 'titlebar',
            title: 'Console'
        },
        {
            xtype: 'container',
            id: 'console'
        }
    ]
}
```

This is the best I can come up with, but since it is getting the entire HTML of a container and then resetting it, this seems very wasteful and just all around bad:

```
    Ext.log = function (msg) {
        var console = Ext.get('console');
        var html = console.getHtml();
        console.setHtml(html + '<div>' + msg + '</div>');
    };
```

There has to be a better way...right?

Comment: try to work without id'. Instead use itemId

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a panel each time and can add it in you container..

```
var myPanel = Ext.create('Ext.Panel', {
    html: 'This will be added to a Container'
});

Ext.getCmp('console').add([myPanel]);
```

Comment: for testing this seems to work, but for other usages, make sure you can destroy the item later on.

Comment: Destroy the panel with the log message? Or destroy the reference to the console?  Would it then be better to use Ext.fly('console')?

Comment: Please don't use a panel when you don't have to. Use the most lightweight possible component. In this case: Ext.Component

Answer (score 1):

If you just need the message for a short period, you can add:

```
var actionSheet = Ext.create('Ext.ActionSheet', {
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'container',
            html  : 'My Message',
            style: 'color: white;'
        }
    ],
    itemId: 'debugMessage',
    listeners: {
        show: function () {
            Ext.defer(function(){
                Ext.Viewport.down('.container[itemId=debugMessage]').hide();
                Ext.defer(function(){
                    Ext.Viewport.down('.container[itemId=debugMessage]').destroy();
                },250);
            },1400);
        }
    }
});
Ext.Viewport.add(actionSheet);
actionSheet.show();
```